# How do I play audio CDs in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, multimedia

Audio CDs play fine in Ubuntu 11.10 but in Kubuntu 11.10, even with AmaroK 2.5, audio CDs appear as playback devices and can also be ripped but I cannot play the CDs directly. AmaroK shows the CD tracks but trying to play them after adding them to the playlist does nothing. In Bangarang, CD tracks don't show up at all. KsCD crashes and does not start.

In Clementine, CDs don't show up. In MPlayer and its front-ends, including SMPlayer and UMPlayer, the CD sound stutters because, according to the MPlayer log, the CD cache for MPlayer does not respond (irrespective of the cache size). In Kaffeine with Xine, the CD plays (at least the first track) but there is no list of tracks and neither can I skip tracks.

GNOME-based CD players such as Sound Juicer and Goobox pull in half of GNOME itself, which is undesirable. So, I seem to have run out of options, except for VLC, Winamp-inspired (Qmmp, Audacious) and Mono (Banshee), all of which I want to avoid. Is there any way to make audio CDs play with either GStreamer, Xine or MPlayer (preferably GStreamer)?

Answer (score 1):

**Something is broken**

Kubuntu 11.10 / KDE 4.7 / Amarok 2.4.3 - 2.5.0

I can't get the Amarok to play the CD's. And same thing seems to be with other users: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56320-Playing-CDs-in-Amarok.

With the Bangarang (2.1) the CD'a play if i use the Xine Phonon backend. The Xine backend has been deprecated and removed from the Ubuntu repositories. I'm using the Xine Phonon backend from the Natty - phonon-backend-xine_4.7.0really4.4.4-0ubuntu3_i386.deb.

[image]

**How i play the CD's**

I'm using the cdtool.

```
:~$ apt-cache show cdtool

Description: text-based audio CD player and CD-ROM control commands
 cdtool contains cdplay, cdeject, cdstop, cdpause, and several other
 programs for playing audio CDs and controlling a CD-ROM drive from
 the command line and in a quick and scriptable way.
 .
 cdown reads track info and queries a CDDB database for info on
 the current CD. cdctrl is a command line utility for controlling a
 CD-ROM drive interactively and from scripts. cdir keeps track of the
 contents of different CDs using a workman-compatible database.
```

.

```
man cdtool

NAME
       cdtool - play and catalog audio CDROMs on CDROM drive(s)

SYNOPSIS
       cdeject   [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]
       cdclose   [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]
       cdir -n   [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-r|-s|-t|-V|-?|-h]
       cdinfo    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-a|-r|-s|-t|-v|-V|-?|-h]
       cdpause   [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]
       cdplay    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [start [stop]
       cdplay    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [+|- number]
       cdplay    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [start|stop|resume|eject|close|info|dir]
       cdplay    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]
       cdstop    [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]
       cdvolume  [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h|level]
       cdshuffle [-[0..9]|-d device]  [-V|-?|-h]

DESCRIPTION
       The cdeject command ejects the current compact disc.

       The cdclose command closes the CDROM tray.

       The  cdir  command  lists information about the currently loaded audio 
       compact disc.  In particular, it lists the lengths of all tracks...
```

That is: Alt+F2 and cdplay, cdstop, ...

[image]

Comment: On `Lubuntu, 16_04` the commands do not work. Neither with `alt f2` nor on the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

`kscd` worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install -y kscd
```